# how to download a xlsx using Ajax HTTP GET with EXTJS?

Tags: java, ajax, extjs

I have a question that may been easy for some to answer...

I have this Java method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/exportEditableFields", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  @ResponseBody

  public void exportEditableFields(
  @RequestParam(value = "conversationId") final String conversationId,@RequestParam(
  value = "schoolId") final Long schoolId,
  @RequestParam(value = "schoolAbbreviation") final String schoolAbbreviation,
final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_hhmm");
School school = schoolService.getSchoolById(schoolId);
String fileName =
    String.format("SDMS-%s-%s-Editable Fields-%s", school.getAbbreviation(), school.getName(),
        dateFormat.format(new Date()));
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
fileName = fileName + ".xlsx";

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
    + fileName + "\"");

BufferedOutputStream bos =
    new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
exportManager.writeFieldRecords(bos, schoolId);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
bos.flush();
response.flushBuffer();
}
```

I am invoking this method using EXTJS this way:

```
  listeners: {
                click: function(){
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        disableCaching: false,
                        method: 'GET',
                        params: {
                          conversationId : this.conversationId,
                          schoolId       : Ext.getStore('DataStore').getProxy().extraParams.schoolId,
                          schoolAbbreviation: Ext.getStore('DataStore').getProxy().extraParams.schoolAbbreviation
                        },
                        url: 'export/exportEditableFields',
                        success: function(r, opts) {
                             var resp    = Ext.decode(r.responseText);
                             var b =1;
                                Ext.DomHelper.append(Ext.getBody(), { 
                                  tag:          'iframe', 
                                  frameBorder:  0, 
                                  width:        0, 
                                  height:       0, 
                                  css:          'display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;', 
                                  src:          resp.downloadUrl 
                                });                             },
                        failure: function(response, opts) {
                           console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
                        }
                     });
                }
```

the problem is from the browser I can't download the xlsx that the java method generates.
Any idea ?

how i should process the success response to download the file?
I am using EXTJS 4.2, Tomcat 7, Java 7

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197418/file-download-in-javascript-using-ajax-call/32197976#32197976

Comment: Thanks all!
The problem was solved using window.open(url, '_self');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all! The problem was solved using window.open(url, '_self');

Answer (score 1):

For downloading a file in ExtJs, you have to use `form.submit()` instead of `Ajax`.It's target should be `iframe`

Comment: I try, didn't work... The Java method is working right. Is being called for other funcionality of the Application.

Comment: `'export/exportEditableFields'` will initiate uploading of file or it will just generate the upload url?